# Is this test comparing jQuery and querySelectorAll accurate?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, performance-testing

This [test](https://jsperf.com/getelementsbyclassname-vs-queryselectorall/18) is quite old but it still shows that jQuery selects (based on a class) much faster than querySelectorAll. For me on Chrome 75 the results were the following.

```
Method                 | Ops/sec
-----------------------|------------
getElementsByClassName | 1,484,860
querySelectorAll       | 79,802
jQuery                 | 464,550
```

The issue was [discussed and supposedly fixed](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=253425) six years ago. But today qSA still appears incredibly slow. Is that the reality and qSA's performance is so bad? Or is there some error in the test?

Comment: I'm guessing making it even faster than it is isn't a priority, as it's already extremely fast, not "incredibly slow." Sure, it could be faster, and it's odd that the issue says it's been fixed (must have regressed since then, perhaps with some reason, though...). What real world problem is this causing for you?

Comment: That test is deceiving. Try one with multiple selectors or thousands of elements and you will see much more comparable performance. Internally, if jQuery sees that the selector is a single ID or className, it will use `getElementById()` or `getElementsByClassName()` to speed up its performance. If you start adding multiple classes or other types of selectors, it has to switch to `querySelectorAll()` (or other methods if the browser doesn't support it) and its performance gets much worse.

Comment: @skyline3000 according to the chromium issue that I linked in the question, it should also be using getElementsByClassName internally in this case.

Comment: Indeed there is code in the Blink source for fast queries with a single ID, class, or tag: https://github.com/chromium/chromium/blob/6efa1184771ace08f3e2162b0255c93526d1750d/third_party/blink/renderer/core/css/selector_query.cc#L448  So it's a bit of a mystery, perhaps it doesn't actually get used.